# Wrong parameter count for max()

Tags: php, while-loop, max

I'm trying to show the max value of column teams from mysql. Above the while loop I've selected teams from my mysql table and then as you can see in my code below I have included max($teams) - but it is returning an error? Where am I going wrong.

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

$teams = $rows['teams'];


if($teams > "1") {

echo '<div class="bestbettor">'.'<span class="redtext">'."Bettor: ".'</span>'. $rows['username'].'</div>'; 
echo '<div class="bestbettor">'.'<span class="redtext">'."   Bet: ".'</span>'.max($teams). " team accumulator".'</span>'.'</div>'; 
}

}
```

Comment: What does your query look like?  Also, it seems like you want a max value from a MAX() in the query, not a php function max() of $team.

Comment: Sounds like you want to be doing `SELECT MAX(something) AS teams FROM ...` in your query, PHP's `max()` expects multiple values and will return the highest value of all the arguments (or the highest array element with a single array argument).

Comment: **Don't use the old MySQL extension!** Better use MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: thanks - I did try using MAX on my query but it didn't work. Not it does!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must pass an array to [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php).

```
$teams = $rows['teams']; // saves as string.
```

if your teams were delimited by a comma then you could do something like:

```
$teams = explode(",",$rows['teams']); // saves as array
```

then you could do max()

Answer (score 1):

If one parameter is given to `max()` it has to be an array of values of which `max()` will return the highest value in that array. It seems like you've just given it a single string.